# Uploads directory is not writable

Tags: php

I've recently just moved my server to a new host and I'm now having problems with my PHP upload form. Files can not be uploaded. The error I get is:

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(/public_html/site/abc/uploads/APLICATION.doc)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /long/path/apply.php on line 389
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move '/tmp/phpDAz5QP' to
>   '/public_html/site/uploads/1908131216_APPLICATION.doc' in
>   /long/path/apply.php on line 389 Problem: Could not move file to
>   destination directory not writable /tmp/phpDAz5QP -
>   /public_html/site/abc/uploads/1908131216__APPLICATION.doc

I have this little test to see if the directory is writable, and it's not.

```
$upload_dir = "/public_html/site/$companyfolder/uploads";
if(!is_writable($upload_dir)) {
    $writable = 'not writable';
} else {
    $writable = 'writable';
}
echo $writable;
```

I have the uploads folder set to 777 for permissions. Any ideas of why the directory is not writable?

Comment: You may need to change the folder permission from the control panel. Sometimes changing folder permission through FTP is not effective. You  have to go to cPanel and do it.

Comment: Your path is wrong, shouldn't it be `/home/youruser/public_html/site/$companyfolder/uploads`? Or have you actually created a folder called public_html at the root of your HD `/`

Comment: Are you sure that your path is correct? PHP takes absolute paths so your "root" is not your website root directory but it's your filesystem root. EDIT: Oh sorry too late

Comment: also depending upon the server there might be other things going on, etc. which prevent writing to 777 dirs.  check with your webhost if you need 777 or not (shared hosting, things like suphp can make php run as your user, thus not needing world writable which is a security risk)

Comment: @Fred-ii- that is given that is his actual folder which does not look like it is "/public_html" seem very oddly.

Comment: @Prix Yes, I just noticed that now. There's quite a bit of contradiction happening with the OP's code, and not seeing full code doesn't help neither.

Comment: @Prix Thank you! That did the trick...adding /home/youruser/ to the beginning fixed it. Appreciate it!

Comment: `move_uploaded_Files()` works at the filesystem level. It does NOT understand or care about your URL-space web-based paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your above code, it seems your upload path is incorrect:

```
$upload_dir = "/public_html/site/$companyfolder/uploads";
```

Should have been something like:

```
$upload_dir = "/home/youruser/public_html/site/{$companyfolder}/uploads";
```

The directory needs to be the absolute path or relative. When it's relative, it needs to be relative to where the PHP being called is at.

So you could have used it as `./site/{$companyfolder}/uploads` for example, that is given your php code being used is at `/home/youruser/public_html`.